# PouchDB + Conflict Resolution

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have a really simple question about hard topic:

How does conflict resolution work in PouchDB?

I looked at the documentation, as well as quickly googling, but it didn't help. So, how to do I handle conflict management in my application which is using PouchDB?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you do it in CouchDB, which you can directly translate into PouchDB terms since the APIs are exactly the same.

You fetch a document, using `conflicts=true` to ask for conflicts (`get()` with `{conflicts:true}` in PouchDB):

```
http://localhost:5984/db1/foo?conflicts=true
```

You receive a doc like this:

```
{
"_id":"foo",
"_rev":"2-f3d4c66dcd7596419c76b2498b3ba21f",
"notgonnawork":"this is from the second db",
"_conflicts":["2-c1592ce7b31cc26e91d2f2029c57e621"]
}
```

There is a conflict introduced from another database, and that database's revision has (randomly) won. If you used bi-directional replication, both databases will provide this same answer.

Notice that both revisions start with "2-." This indicates that they are both the second revision to the document, and they both live at the same level of the revision tree.

Using the revision ID, you fetch the conflicting version (`get()` with `{rev=...}` in PouchDB:

```
http://localhost:5984/db1/foo?rev=2-c1592ce7b31cc26e91d2f2029c57e621
```

You receive:

```
{
"_id":"foo",
"_rev":"2-c1592ce7b31cc26e91d2f2029c57e621",
"notgonnawork":"this is from the first database"
}
```

After presenting the two conflicting versions to the user, you can then `PUT` (`put()`) a third revision on top of both of these. Your third version can combine the results, choose the loser, or whatever you want.

Advanced reading:

- [The CouchDB docs on conflict resolution](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html)
- [The CouchDB wiki page on conflicts.](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts)
- [Understanding CouchDB Conflicts by Jan Lenhardt](http://writing.jan.io/2013/12/19/understanding-couchdb-conflicts.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But question is more - how to sync items when you have live replication On?

Comment: For a tutorial on conflict resolution during live replication see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434686/pouchdb-how-to-resolve-conflicts-with-continuous-replication