# CouchDB conflicts

Tags: ionic-framework, couchdb, conflict, pouchdb

I am developing an Ionic app that uses pouchDB/couchDB to keep data in a shared DB.
I am facing this issue:
if I run the app on two mobile phones, and both try to modify the same document in couchDB, they will be in conflict.
Is there a way to handle this server side? Or is there a way to handle this client side, better than put the document, get the document to see if there are conflicts, modify the document creating a new rev if there are conflicts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I point you to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450495/pouchdb-conflict-resolution) to similar issue from Nolan Lawson.

There is not an automatic conflict resolution in CouchDB/PouchDB, the resolution should be part of your business logic.