# Multiple unique field constraints and eventual conflict resolution in PouchDB and Couchbase

Tags: pouchdb

I was unable to find proper solution to handle "**Eventual conflicts**" (see http://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html for "Eventual conflicts" description) when I have document with multiple unique field constraints, like unique username constraint and unique email constraint for user registration document or Article document with unique name and title + all the documents are replicating live on mobile devices using **Ionic + PouchDB** and **Couchbase Sync Gateway**.

Let's take for example `Article` document with unique `name` constraint and unique `title` constraint.

1). I have `Article` document which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9",
  "_rev": "1-8b8076d3fef9994ca65a516532c5f975"
  "type": "Article",
  "name": "name1",
  "title": "title1",
  "owner": "user-id-here"
}
```

2). Also, I'm creating separate constraint documents for each unique field (see [Unique constraints in couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541239/unique-constraints-in-couchdb) and https://kfalck.net/2009/06/29/enforcing-unique-usernames-on-couchdb) with "**_id**" key in format "**{doc type}--constraint-unique--{unique property / field name}::{hashed value of the property in sha256}**".

So, for the above doc with "**name1**" and "**title1**" I'm creating two "**ConstraintUnique**" docs / placeholders for `name` field and for `title` field.

Unique "name" field placeholder doc:

```
{
  "_id": "article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
  "_rev": "1-de7e0636632764e97880f362d50598b7",
  "type": "ConstraintUnique",
  "docRef": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9",
  "propertyName": "name",
  "propertyValue": "name1"
}
```

Unique "title" field placeholder doc:

```
{
  "_id": "article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7",
  "_rev": "1-34c1771f2108f6ad8efc0d99e79d78a0",
  "type": "ConstraintUnique",
  "docRef": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9",
  "propertyName": "title",
  "propertyValue": "title1"
}
```

On all "**ConstraintUnique**" docs I have "**docRef**" field which points to "**_id**" of actual doc like "**Article._id**"

3). This way, if I want to add in the future more unique constraints I will just add another "**ConstraintUnique**" and when I'm saving/creating  a new article I'm checking for existing "constraint docs" and then save or reject the original doc. Another option will be to insert the doc without additional "constraint docs" and check if there is a duplicate using views and delete the duplicate straight away. (all is described here: [Unique constraints in couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541239/unique-constraints-in-couchdb)).

***The problem:***

I'm doing live bidirectional replication (client to server and server to client sync) like this:

```
db.sync('remote db url', {
  live: true,
  retry: true
})
```

Then, I listen for changes like this:

```
db.changes({
  since: 'now',
  live: true,
  include_docs: true,
  conflicts: true
}).on('change', function(change) {
  if (change.doc._conflicts) {
    // do coflict resolution
  }
});
```

and I have following scenario where both users are OFFLINE and NO data is synced to remote DB, but it is inserted in their local dbs:

1). `User1` is offline and he inserted `Article` with `name1` and `title1`, his local db will look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
  "_rev": "1-de7e0636632764e97880f362d50598b7",
  "type": "ConstraintUnique",
  "docRef": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9",
  "propertyName": "name",
  "propertyValue": "name1"
}

{
  "_id": "article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7",
  "_rev": "1-34c1771f2108f6ad8efc0d99e79d78a0",
  "type": "ConstraintUnique",
  "docRef": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9",
  "propertyName": "title",
  "propertyValue": "title1"
}

{
  "_id": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9",
  "_rev": "1-8b8076d3fef9994ca65a516532c5f975"
  "type": "Article",
  "name": "name1",
  "title": "title1",
  "owner": "user1"
}
```

2). `User2` is also offline, and he is inserting same `Article` with `name1` and `title1`, so his local db will look almost the same, but with different `Article._id` and the same `ConstraintUnique` ids:

```
Same as User1's (except _rev and docRef):
{
  "_id": "article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
  "_rev": "1-5c427cba5efe71114acb7e6ddd8b8a23",
  "type": "ConstraintUnique",
  "docRef": "article::ad16f2e4-9cff-42ae-ae92-27e353e7f229",
  "propertyName": "name",
  "propertyValue": "name1"
}

Same as User1's (except _rev and docRef):
{
  "_id": "article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7",
  "_rev": "1-14244246dbbac7e55e132abe47fe115d",
  "type": "ConstraintUnique",
  "docRef": "article::ad16f2e4-9cff-42ae-ae92-27e353e7f229",
  "propertyName": "title",
  "propertyValue": "title1"
}

Different, but the actual data is the same:
{
  "_id": "article::ad16f2e4-9cff-42ae-ae92-27e353e7f229",
  "_rev": "1-8b8076d3fef9994ca65a516532c5f975"
  "type": "Article",
  "name": "name1",
  "title": "title1",
  "owner": "user2"
}
```

3). The actual problem:

When `User 1` is back online and his changes are synced with the remote database without conflict:

```
Ids of the docs:
"_id": "article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
"_id": "article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7"
"_id": "article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9"
```

Later, `User 2` is also back online and his changes are synced with the remote database WITH conflict:

```
Ids of the docs:
"_id": "article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855" -- conflicting with the User1
"_id": "article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7" -- conflicting with the User1
"_id": "article::ad16f2e4-9cff-42ae-ae92-27e353e7f229" -- no conflict, but I need to remove this duplicate somehow
```

So, CouchDB / Couchbase Sync Gateway chooses the winner for "**article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855**" and "**article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7**" on the server side, but PouchDB on the client also syncs the duplicated Article doc - I want to clean up constraint docs conflicts ("**article--constraint-unique--name::e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855**" and "**article--constraint-unique--title::5018e26faaec56a465e61aaeb752c2984c8a6d6305c8496b3a95213fb20889c7**") and update **docRef** (if the **docRef** is not the same on both "*name*" and "*title*" constraints), also I want to remove the duplicated Article with ids **"article::3808cea0-bb99-11e5-9ba4-315d40280ab9"(User1)** and **"article::ad16f2e4-9cff-42ae-ae92-27e353e7f229"(User2)** or better I want to choose one winning Article, then update **docRef** in "**article--constraint-unique**" docs. Any solution is welcome - I just want to remove duplicated Article and update constraint placeholders to be in sync with the winning Article.

I've done raw implementation where I check for conflicts in *changes feed* (http://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html), I am using **Ionic 1/AngularJS 1 + PouchDB** and try to delete duplicated doc/Article:

```
var changeListener = db.changes({
  since: 'now',
  live: true,
  include_docs: true,
  conflicts: true
}).on('change', function(change) {
  var doc = angular.copy(change.doc);
  var i;

  if (doc._conflicts) {
    if (doc.type && (doc.type === 'ConstraintUnique')) {
      for (i = 0; i < doc._conflicts.length; i++) {
        (function(currentConflictRev) {
          // get conflicted "ConstraintUnique"
          db.get(doc._id, {rev: currentConflictRev}).then(function(conflictConstraintUniqueDoc) {
            if (conflictConstraintUniqueDoc.docRef) {
              // get linked to "ConstraintUnique" doc and delete it
              db.get(conflictConstraintUniqueDoc.docRef)
                .then(function(conflictDoc) {
                  // delete the duplicated doc
                  db.remove(conflictDoc._id, conflictDoc._rev);
                  // resolve the current conflict
                  db.remove(conflictConstraintUniqueDoc._id, conflictConstraintUniqueDoc._rev);
                });
            }
          });
        })(doc._conflicts[i]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This implementation is not working when Couch server decides that winning "**ConstraintUnique**" doc for **name** is with **docRef==user1Article** and the other winning  "**ConstraintUnique**" doc for **title** is with **docRef==user2Article** - this way both articles are deleted, not only the duplicated one.

I'm sure, I'm doing it wrong: so, how to deal with conflicts and offline client sync where we use documents with unique constraints on their fields in case of eventual conflict / master-master conflict?

More topics are read with no luck on solution:

- [PouchDB + Conflict Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450495/pouchdb-conflict-resolution)
- [How to resolve conflicts with continuous replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434686/pouchdb-how-to-resolve-conflicts-with-continuous-replication)

Thank you very much in advance!